# Error in pie() : 'x' values must be positive

Tags: r, graph, frequency

All the numbers are positive as you can see in the table. i want to a pie chart of the Relative Frequency with the legends. But before even thinking about making legends..i need to have the pie graph...when i run it..it gives me the same error over and over again. Like all of my x values are positive yet giving me the error. Please help me fix it. Thank you.

My table:

```
SocialIssue     Frequency   RelFreq
1        Housing       245 0.2401961
2 Transportation       112 0.1098039
3    Health Care       153 0.1500000
4      Education        71 0.0696078
5           Food       133 0.1303922
6          Other       306 0.3000000
```

Code:

```
data1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/jaina/Desktop/Question1CSV.csv", header = T)
data1$RelFreq = data1$Frequency / sum(data1$Frequency)
options(digits = 6)

pie(data1)
```

Error:

```
Error in pie(data1) : 'x' values must be positive
```

Comment: Try pie(data1$RelFreq)

Comment: It gives me 1,2,3,4,5,6... it states how many elements are there not the relative frequency

Comment: Works but can you tell me about the legend like i want to show both the number and the socialIssue on the pie graph

Comment: To add a labels: `pie(data1$RelFreq, legend=paste(data1$SocialIssue, data1$RelFreq))`  See ?pie to see all optional parameters and sample use.